# Socloz MonitoringBundle Profiler arguments

Tags: php, symfony

After installing SoclozMonitoringBundle, I encountered this error:

> ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to
>   Socloz\MonitoringBundle\Listener\Profiler::__construct() must be an
>   instance of Socloz\MonitoringBundle\Notify\StatsD\StatsDInterface,
>   null given, called in
>   /project/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 5127
>   and defined in
>   /project/vendor/socloz/monitoring-bundle/Listener/Profiler.php line 58

app/config/config/yml

```
socloz_monitoring:
    exceptions:
        enable: true
    profiler:
        enable: true
        request: true
    mailer:
        enable: true
        from: monitor@mail.com
        to: monitor@mail.com
    statsd:
        enable: false
        host: nowhere
        port: 42
        merge_packets: true
```

Did I forget something ?

I would like to know execution time of my rest api in production. And other stats of functions.

Thanks in advance.

Tanguy

Answer (score 0):

Replace (https://github.com/SoCloz/SoclozMonitoringBundle/blob/master/Listener/Profiler.php#L58):

```
public function __construct(Xhprof $profiler, StatsDInterface $statsd, Logger $logger = null, $sampling = 100)
```

by:

```
public function __construct(Xhprof $profiler, StatsDInterface $statsd = null, Logger $logger = null, $sampling = 100)
```

See : https://github.com/SoCloz/SoclozMonitoringBundle/issues/19